# React Firestore data retrieval into array not working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So, I am trying to retrieve data from my firestore and display it onto my webpage, I have tried everything and exhausted every question on this site to no avail.

When I use the code below, nothing renders on the website page, however when I use the commented code with dummy data instead of the firestore query retrieval data, the data renders as it should.

I have used console.log() on both the dummy data and the firestore data and they both log the same data array.

I am confused as to why the firestore data is not displaying the matches even though the array is saved correctly.

```
class MatchHistoryForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    var Matches = [];
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("Matches")
      .orderBy("date")
      .limit(10)
      .get()
      .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          Matches.push({
            team1: doc.data().team1,
            team2: doc.data().team2,
            winner: doc.data().winner,
            date: doc.data().date
          });
        });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
      });

    // var Matches = [{
    //  team1: "asdf",
    //  team2: "jkl",
    //  winner: "team1",
    //  date: "1/2/2018",
    // }, {
    //  team1: "qwer",
    //  team2: "yuio",
    //  winner: "team2",
    //  date: "1/8/2018",
    // }];

    console.log(Matches);
    this.state = {
      Matches: Matches
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="against">
        {this.state.Matches.map(v => {
          return (
            <p>
              Team1: {v.team1}, Team2: {v.team2}, Winner: {v.winner}, Date:{v.date}
            </p>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The firebase request is asynchronous, so it will not be completed before the constructor is run.

You could put that logic in `componentDidMount` instead and use `setState` to update `Matches` when it is done:

**Example**

```jsx
class MatchHistoryForm extends Component {
  state = { Matches: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("Matches")
      .orderBy("date")
      .limit(10)
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        const Matches = [];

        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          Matches.push({
            team1: doc.data().team1,
            team2: doc.data().team2,
            winner: doc.data().winner,
            date: doc.data().date
          });
        });

        this.setState({ Matches });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="against">
        {this.state.Matches.map(v => {
          return (
            <p>
              Team1: {v.team1},
              Team2: {v.team2},
              Winner: {v.winner},
              Date: {v.date}
            </p>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```